# How do I read this object in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I wanna read this object in typescript but I have no idea how to access keys with dot in them.

```js
{ 
    id: '2db232c9-87ee-4cde-ace1-23bc18722f2d',
    code: 'BPT',
    name: 'Basic Programming',
    basePrice: 200,
    description: null,
    isCalibration: false,
    createdAt: 2020-09-14T15:35:51.526Z,
    updatedAt: 2020-09-14T15:35:51.526Z,
    deletedAt: null,
    'testSection.id': 'f7c228aa-224e-4376-8170-8135077a9e6b',
    'testSection.testTypeId': '2db232c9-87ee-4cde-ace1-23bc18722f2d',
    'testSection.testSectionCategory.categoryName': 'DSA-CAT2',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the square brackets syntax like this `obj['testSection.id']` for example. It works for every special character that is considered incorrect when in a variable name (like carets, etc...)

Comment: Actually I have many results in an Array. So when I try arr[0]['testSection.id'] it gives error saying identifier expected

Comment: @KunalShukla for me it works perfectly fine even with objects in a array. Assuming that your code is correct, because I had to add quotes in the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` properties.

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets property access:

```
console.log(obj['testSection.id']) // 'f7c228aa-224e-4376-8170-8135077a9e6b'
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an issue with two keys mentioned below, they should be `strings`

```
createdAt: '2020-09-14-T15:35:51.526Z',
updatedAt: '2020-09-14-T15:35:51.526Z',
```

```js
let obj = { 
    id: '2db232c9-87ee-4cde-ace1-23bc18722f2d',
    code: 'BPT',
    name: 'Basic Programming',
    basePrice: 200,
    description: null,
    isCalibration: false,
    createdAt: '2020-09-14-T15:35:51.526Z',
    updatedAt: '2020-09-14-T15:35:51.526Z',
    deletedAt: null,
    'testSection.id': 'f7c228aa-224e-4376-8170-8135077a9e6b',
    'testSection.testTypeId': '2db232c9-87ee-4cde-ace1-23bc18722f2d',
    'testSection.testSectionCategory.categoryName': 'DSA-CAT2',
}

console.log(obj["testSection.id"]);
console.log(obj["testSection.testTypeId"]);
console.log(obj["testSection.testSectionCategory.categoryName"]);
```